# Adding quotes to a number in a string

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have the following **almost** JSON string:

```
<?php
$string = '{0:{"id":1,"name":"Antiek en Kunst","subs":[{"id":2,"name":"Antiek | Bestek"},{"id":3,"name":"Antiek | Boeken en Bijbels"},{"id":1100,"name":"Antiek | Emaille"},{"id":1501,"name":"Antiek | Gereedschap en Instrumenten"},{"id":1648,"name":"Antiek | Glas en Kristal"},{"id":2614,"name":"Antiek | Goud en Zilver"},{"id":2661,"name":"Antiek | Kandelaars"},{"id":1841,"name":"Antiek | Kantoor en Zakelijk"},{"id":1502,"name":"Antiek | Keramiek en Aardewerk"},{"id":1842,"name":"Antiek | Keukenbenodigdheden"},{"id":2118,"name":"Antiek | Kleden en Textiel"},{"id":1503,"name":"Antiek | Kleding en Accessoires"},{"id":6,"name":"Antiek | Klokken"},{"id":1647,"name":"Antiek | Koper en Brons"},{"id":7,"name":"Antiek | Lampen"},{"id":1504,"name":"Antiek | Meubels | Bedden"},{"id":5,"name":"Antiek | Meubels | Kasten"},{"id":1505,"name":"Antiek | Meubels | Stoelen en Banken"},{"id":1506,"name":"Antiek | Meubels | Tafels"},{"id":1101,"name":"Antiek | Naaimachines"},{"id":10,"name":"Antiek | Porselein"},{"id":1102,"name":"Antiek | Religie"},{"id":1103,"name":"Antiek | Schalen"},{"id":2662,"name":"Antiek | Schoolplaten"},{"id":1843,"name":"Antiek | Servies compleet"},{"id":12,"name":"Antiek | Servies los"},{"id":1507,"name":"Antiek | Speelgoed"},{"id":2663,"name":"Antiek | Spiegels"},{"id":2664,"name":"Antiek | Tin"},{"id":11,"name":"Antiek | Tv's en Audio"},{"id":14,"name":"Antiek | Vazen"},{"id":1104,"name":"Antiek | Wandborden en Tegels"},{"id":1500,"name":"Antiek | Woonaccessoires"},{"id":9,"name":"Antiek | Overige"},{"id":15,"name":"Curiosa en Brocante"},{"id":1423,"name":"Diensten | Kunstenaars en Portretschilders"},{"id":2610,"name":"Diensten | Reparatie en Onderhoud"},{"id":23,"name":"Kunst | Beelden en Houtsnijwerken"},{"id":1508,"name":"Kunst | Designobjecten"},{"id":1105,"name":"Kunst | Etsen en Gravures"},{"id":27,"name":"Kunst | Litho's en Zeefdrukken"},{"id":1844,"name":"Kunst | Niet-Westerse kunst"},{"id":1846,"name":"Kunst | Schilderijen | Abstract"},{"id":25,"name":"Kunst | Schilderijen | Klassiek"},{"id":1845,"name":"Kunst | Schilderijen | Modern"},{"id":26,"name":"Kunst | Tekeningen en Foto's"},{"id":24,"name":"Kunst | Overige"}]},1:{"id":31,"name":"Audio, Tv en Foto","subs":[{"id":2035,"name":"Accu's en Batterijen"},{"id":2617,"name":"Afstandsbedieningen"},{"id":32,"name":"Bandrecorders"},{"id":1132,"name":"Beamers"},{"id":2665,"name":"Blu-ray-spelers en Blu-ray-recorders"},{"id":33,"name":"Buizenversterkers"},{"id":2036,"name":"Cassettedecks"},{"id":35,"name":"Cd-spelers"},{"id":2666,"name":"Diaprojectors"},{"id":2042,"name":"Diensten | Film- en Videobewerking"},{"id":1199,"name":"Diensten | Fotografen"},{"id":1219,"name":"Diensten | Reparaties"},{"id":1114,"name":"Dvd-spelers en Dvd-recorders"},{"id":1115,"name":"Films 8mm, 16mm en 35mm"},{"id":1360,"name":"Fotografie | Accu's en Batterijen"},{"id":480,"name":"Fotografie | Camera's | Analoog"},{"id":487,"name":"Fotografie | Camera's | Digitaal"},{"id":2667,"name":"Fotografie | Digitale fotolijstjes"},{"id":488,"name":"Fotografie | Doka Toebehoren"},{"id":1720,"name":"Fotografie | Filters"},{"id":489,"name":"Fotografie | Flitsers"},{"id":1483,"name":"Fotografie | Fotolijsten en Fotoalbums"},{"id":1721,"name":"Fotografie | Fotoprinters en Fotopapier"},{"id":1400,"name":"Fotografie | Fotostudio en Toebehoren"},{"id":1484,"name":"Fotografie | Fototassen"},{"id":493,"name":"Fotografie | Geheugenkaarten"},{"id":495,"name":"Fotografie | Lenzen en Objectieven"},{"id":497,"name":"Fotografie | Onderwatercamera's"},{"id":501,"name":"Fotografie | Professionele apparatuur"},{"id":500,"name":"Fotografie | Statieven en Balhoofden"},{"id":1722,"name":"Harddiskrecorders"},{"id":1116,"name":"Home Cinema-sets"},{"id":1106,"name":"Kabels"},{"id":37,"name":"Koptelefoons en Headsets"},{"id":38,"name":"Luidsprekers"},{"id":2668,"name":"Mediaspelers"},{"id":40,"name":"Mp3-spelers | Apple iPod"},{"id":1649,"name":"Mp3-spelers | Overige merken"},{"id":1723,"name":"Mp3-spelers | Accessoires | Apple iPod"},{"id":1452,"name":"Mp3-spelers | Accessoires | Overige merken"},{"id":2615,"name":"Mp4-spelers"},{"id":1724,"name":"Opladers"},{"id":496,"name":"Optische apparatuur | Microscopen"},{"id":502,"name":"Optische apparatuur | Telescopen"},{"id":503,"name":"Optische apparatuur | Verrekijkers"},{"id":42,"name":"Platenspelers en Pick-ups"},{"id":1117,"name":"Professionele Audio-, Tv- en Video-apparatuur"},{"id":43,"name":"Radio's"},{"id":36,"name":"Stereo-sets"},{"id":45,"name":"Tuners"},{"id":1118,"name":"Tv-decoders en Schotelantennes"},{"id":1120,"name":"Tv's | Plasma, Lcd en Led"},{"id":1121,"name":"Tv's | Overige Tv's"},{"id":1453,"name":"Tv's | Accessoires"},{"id":46,"name":"Versterkers en Receivers"},{"id":1129,"name":"Videobewakingsapparatuur"},{"id":1130,"name":"Videocamera's | Analoog"},{"id":1131,"name":"Videocamera's | Digitaal"},{"id":1133,"name":"Videospelers en Videorecorders"},{"id":47,"name":"Walkmans, Discmans en Minidiscspelers"},{"id":1725,"name":"Weerstations en Barometers"},{"id":41,"name":"Overige Audio, Tv en Foto"}]}}';

?>
```

I need to convert all the integers to strings, this can be done with adding double quotes (`"`) to them. However, how would the be done? It doesn't need to be PHP specific, notepad++ is able to use regexes to search and replace but I'm not sure if this is the right method to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that the current format is syntactically invalid and the desired format would be *technically* invalid JSON (i.e. numbers should not be quoted).

Comment: Jason, are strings containing only numbers disallowed in JSON? I think not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=[{:,])\d+(?=[:,])/', '"\\0"', $string);
```

Comment: According to `jsonlint`, it expects the zero `0` to be a string. I cannot parse this string using PHP, it will return `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, it working better now. But same issue as with @GermanRumm's answer: it also changes integers which reside inside a string, for example: `{"id":2127,"name":"Modelauto's | "1":5 tot "1":12"}`. As you see the `1` is now `"1"`.

Comment: It's working almost, one last thing: it doesn't quote the "other" integers, the ones which start a new category. Like: `},1:{`, `},2:{` etcetera. You can find the current JSON string here: http://pasteit.cc/b50

Answer (score -1):

While converting integers to strings would be a wrong thing to do (in JSON numbers should not be in quotes), technically, what you're looking for is:

```
$string = '{0:{"id":1,"name":"Antiek en Kunst","subs":[{"id":2,"name":"Antiek | Bestek"},{"id":3,"name":"Antiek | Boeken en Bijbels"},{"id":1100,"name":"Antiek | Emaille"},{"id":1501,"name":"Antiek | Gereedschap en Instrumenten"},{"id":1648,"name":"Antiek | Glas en Kristal"},{"id":2614,"name":"Antiek | Goud en Zilver"},{"id":2661,"name":"Antiek | Kandelaars"},{"id":1841,"name":"Antiek | Kantoor en Zakelijk"},{"id":1502,"name":"Antiek | Keramiek en Aardewerk"},{"id":1842,"name":"Antiek | Keukenbenodigdheden"},{"id":2118,"name":"Antiek | Kleden en Textiel"},{"id":1503,"name":"Antiek | Kleding en Accessoires"},{"id":6,"name":"Antiek | Klokken"},{"id":1647,"name":"Antiek | Koper en Brons"},{"id":7,"name":"Antiek | Lampen"},{"id":1504,"name":"Antiek | Meubels | Bedden"},{"id":5,"name":"Antiek | Meubels | Kasten"},{"id":1505,"name":"Antiek | Meubels | Stoelen en Banken"},{"id":1506,"name":"Antiek | Meubels | Tafels"},{"id":1101,"name":"Antiek | Naaimachines"},{"id":10,"name":"Antiek | Porselein"},{"id":1102,"name":"Antiek | Religie"},{"id":1103,"name":"Antiek | Schalen"},{"id":2662,"name":"Antiek | Schoolplaten"},{"id":1843,"name":"Antiek | Servies compleet"},{"id":12,"name":"Antiek | Servies los"},{"id":1507,"name":"Antiek | Speelgoed"},{"id":2663,"name":"Antiek | Spiegels"},{"id":2664,"name":"Antiek | Tin"},{"id":11,"name":"Antiek | Tv's en Audio"},{"id":14,"name":"Antiek | Vazen"},{"id":1104,"name":"Antiek | Wandborden en Tegels"},{"id":1500,"name":"Antiek | Woonaccessoires"},{"id":9,"name":"Antiek | Overige"},{"id":15,"name":"Curiosa en Brocante"},{"id":1423,"name":"Diensten | Kunstenaars en Portretschilders"},{"id":2610,"name":"Diensten | Reparatie en Onderhoud"},{"id":23,"name":"Kunst | Beelden en Houtsnijwerken"},{"id":1508,"name":"Kunst | Designobjecten"},{"id":1105,"name":"Kunst | Etsen en Gravures"},{"id":27,"name":"Kunst | Litho's en Zeefdrukken"},{"id":1844,"name":"Kunst | Niet-Westerse kunst"},{"id":1846,"name":"Kunst | Schilderijen | Abstract"},{"id":25,"name":"Kunst | Schilderijen | Klassiek"},{"id":1845,"name":"Kunst | Schilderijen | Modern"},{"id":26,"name":"Kunst | Tekeningen en Foto's"},{"id":24,"name":"Kunst | Overige"}]},1:{"id":31,"name":"Audio, Tv en Foto","subs":[{"id":2035,"name":"Accu's en Batterijen"},{"id":2617,"name":"Afstandsbedieningen"},{"id":32,"name":"Bandrecorders"},{"id":1132,"name":"Beamers"},{"id":2665,"name":"Blu-ray-spelers en Blu-ray-recorders"},{"id":33,"name":"Buizenversterkers"},{"id":2036,"name":"Cassettedecks"},{"id":35,"name":"Cd-spelers"},{"id":2666,"name":"Diaprojectors"},{"id":2042,"name":"Diensten | Film- en Videobewerking"},{"id":1199,"name":"Diensten | Fotografen"},{"id":1219,"name":"Diensten | Reparaties"},{"id":1114,"name":"Dvd-spelers en Dvd-recorders"},{"id":1115,"name":"Films 8mm, 16mm en 35mm"},{"id":1360,"name":"Fotografie | Accu's en Batterijen"},{"id":480,"name":"Fotografie | Camera's | Analoog"},{"id":487,"name":"Fotografie | Camera's | Digitaal"},{"id":2667,"name":"Fotografie | Digitale fotolijstjes"},{"id":488,"name":"Fotografie | Doka Toebehoren"},{"id":1720,"name":"Fotografie | Filters"},{"id":489,"name":"Fotografie | Flitsers"},{"id":1483,"name":"Fotografie | Fotolijsten en Fotoalbums"},{"id":1721,"name":"Fotografie | Fotoprinters en Fotopapier"},{"id":1400,"name":"Fotografie | Fotostudio en Toebehoren"},{"id":1484,"name":"Fotografie | Fototassen"},{"id":493,"name":"Fotografie | Geheugenkaarten"},{"id":495,"name":"Fotografie | Lenzen en Objectieven"},{"id":497,"name":"Fotografie | Onderwatercamera's"},{"id":501,"name":"Fotografie | Professionele apparatuur"},{"id":500,"name":"Fotografie | Statieven en Balhoofden"},{"id":1722,"name":"Harddiskrecorders"},{"id":1116,"name":"Home Cinema-sets"},{"id":1106,"name":"Kabels"},{"id":37,"name":"Koptelefoons en Headsets"},{"id":38,"name":"Luidsprekers"},{"id":2668,"name":"Mediaspelers"},{"id":40,"name":"Mp3-spelers | Apple iPod"},{"id":1649,"name":"Mp3-spelers | Overige merken"},{"id":1723,"name":"Mp3-spelers | Accessoires | Apple iPod"},{"id":1452,"name":"Mp3-spelers | Accessoires | Overige merken"},{"id":2615,"name":"Mp4-spelers"},{"id":1724,"name":"Opladers"},{"id":496,"name":"Optische apparatuur | Microscopen"},{"id":502,"name":"Optische apparatuur | Telescopen"},{"id":503,"name":"Optische apparatuur | Verrekijkers"},{"id":42,"name":"Platenspelers en Pick-ups"},{"id":1117,"name":"Professionele Audio-, Tv- en Video-apparatuur"},{"id":43,"name":"Radio's"},{"id":36,"name":"Stereo-sets"},{"id":45,"name":"Tuners"},{"id":1118,"name":"Tv-decoders en Schotelantennes"},{"id":1120,"name":"Tv's | Plasma, Lcd en Led"},{"id":1121,"name":"Tv's | Overige Tv's"},{"id":1453,"name":"Tv's | Accessoires"},{"id":46,"name":"Versterkers en Receivers"},{"id":1129,"name":"Videobewakingsapparatuur"},{"id":1130,"name":"Videocamera's | Analoog"},{"id":1131,"name":"Videocamera's | Digitaal"},{"id":1133,"name":"Videospelers en Videorecorders"},{"id":47,"name":"Walkmans, Discmans en Minidiscspelers"},{"id":1725,"name":"Weerstations en Barometers"},{"id":41,"name":"Overige Audio, Tv en Foto"}]}}';

$result = preg_replace('/\d+/', '"\\0"', $string);
```

**EDIT:** if you want to just convert it into proper JSON, then

```
$string = '{0:{"id":1,"name":"Antiek en Kunst","subs":[{"id":2,"name":"Antiek | Bestek"},{"id":3,"name":"Antiek | Boeken en Bijbels"},{"id":1100,"name":"Antiek | Emaille"},{"id":1501,"name":"Antiek | Gereedschap en Instrumenten"},{"id":1648,"name":"Antiek | Glas en Kristal"},{"id":2614,"name":"Antiek | Goud en Zilver"},{"id":2661,"name":"Antiek | Kandelaars"},{"id":1841,"name":"Antiek | Kantoor en Zakelijk"},{"id":1502,"name":"Antiek | Keramiek en Aardewerk"},{"id":1842,"name":"Antiek | Keukenbenodigdheden"},{"id":2118,"name":"Antiek | Kleden en Textiel"},{"id":1503,"name":"Antiek | Kleding en Accessoires"},{"id":6,"name":"Antiek | Klokken"},{"id":1647,"name":"Antiek | Koper en Brons"},{"id":7,"name":"Antiek | Lampen"},{"id":1504,"name":"Antiek | Meubels | Bedden"},{"id":5,"name":"Antiek | Meubels | Kasten"},{"id":1505,"name":"Antiek | Meubels | Stoelen en Banken"},{"id":1506,"name":"Antiek | Meubels | Tafels"},{"id":1101,"name":"Antiek | Naaimachines"},{"id":10,"name":"Antiek | Porselein"},{"id":1102,"name":"Antiek | Religie"},{"id":1103,"name":"Antiek | Schalen"},{"id":2662,"name":"Antiek | Schoolplaten"},{"id":1843,"name":"Antiek | Servies compleet"},{"id":12,"name":"Antiek | Servies los"},{"id":1507,"name":"Antiek | Speelgoed"},{"id":2663,"name":"Antiek | Spiegels"},{"id":2664,"name":"Antiek | Tin"},{"id":11,"name":"Antiek | Tv's en Audio"},{"id":14,"name":"Antiek | Vazen"},{"id":1104,"name":"Antiek | Wandborden en Tegels"},{"id":1500,"name":"Antiek | Woonaccessoires"},{"id":9,"name":"Antiek | Overige"},{"id":15,"name":"Curiosa en Brocante"},{"id":1423,"name":"Diensten | Kunstenaars en Portretschilders"},{"id":2610,"name":"Diensten | Reparatie en Onderhoud"},{"id":23,"name":"Kunst | Beelden en Houtsnijwerken"},{"id":1508,"name":"Kunst | Designobjecten"},{"id":1105,"name":"Kunst | Etsen en Gravures"},{"id":27,"name":"Kunst | Litho's en Zeefdrukken"},{"id":1844,"name":"Kunst | Niet-Westerse kunst"},{"id":1846,"name":"Kunst | Schilderijen | Abstract"},{"id":25,"name":"Kunst | Schilderijen | Klassiek"},{"id":1845,"name":"Kunst | Schilderijen | Modern"},{"id":26,"name":"Kunst | Tekeningen en Foto's"},{"id":24,"name":"Kunst | Overige"}]},1:{"id":31,"name":"Audio, Tv en Foto","subs":[{"id":2035,"name":"Accu's en Batterijen"},{"id":2617,"name":"Afstandsbedieningen"},{"id":32,"name":"Bandrecorders"},{"id":1132,"name":"Beamers"},{"id":2665,"name":"Blu-ray-spelers en Blu-ray-recorders"},{"id":33,"name":"Buizenversterkers"},{"id":2036,"name":"Cassettedecks"},{"id":35,"name":"Cd-spelers"},{"id":2666,"name":"Diaprojectors"},{"id":2042,"name":"Diensten | Film- en Videobewerking"},{"id":1199,"name":"Diensten | Fotografen"},{"id":1219,"name":"Diensten | Reparaties"},{"id":1114,"name":"Dvd-spelers en Dvd-recorders"},{"id":1115,"name":"Films 8mm, 16mm en 35mm"},{"id":1360,"name":"Fotografie | Accu's en Batterijen"},{"id":480,"name":"Fotografie | Camera's | Analoog"},{"id":487,"name":"Fotografie | Camera's | Digitaal"},{"id":2667,"name":"Fotografie | Digitale fotolijstjes"},{"id":488,"name":"Fotografie | Doka Toebehoren"},{"id":1720,"name":"Fotografie | Filters"},{"id":489,"name":"Fotografie | Flitsers"},{"id":1483,"name":"Fotografie | Fotolijsten en Fotoalbums"},{"id":1721,"name":"Fotografie | Fotoprinters en Fotopapier"},{"id":1400,"name":"Fotografie | Fotostudio en Toebehoren"},{"id":1484,"name":"Fotografie | Fototassen"},{"id":493,"name":"Fotografie | Geheugenkaarten"},{"id":495,"name":"Fotografie | Lenzen en Objectieven"},{"id":497,"name":"Fotografie | Onderwatercamera's"},{"id":501,"name":"Fotografie | Professionele apparatuur"},{"id":500,"name":"Fotografie | Statieven en Balhoofden"},{"id":1722,"name":"Harddiskrecorders"},{"id":1116,"name":"Home Cinema-sets"},{"id":1106,"name":"Kabels"},{"id":37,"name":"Koptelefoons en Headsets"},{"id":38,"name":"Luidsprekers"},{"id":2668,"name":"Mediaspelers"},{"id":40,"name":"Mp3-spelers | Apple iPod"},{"id":1649,"name":"Mp3-spelers | Overige merken"},{"id":1723,"name":"Mp3-spelers | Accessoires | Apple iPod"},{"id":1452,"name":"Mp3-spelers | Accessoires | Overige merken"},{"id":2615,"name":"Mp4-spelers"},{"id":1724,"name":"Opladers"},{"id":496,"name":"Optische apparatuur | Microscopen"},{"id":502,"name":"Optische apparatuur | Telescopen"},{"id":503,"name":"Optische apparatuur | Verrekijkers"},{"id":42,"name":"Platenspelers en Pick-ups"},{"id":1117,"name":"Professionele Audio-, Tv- en Video-apparatuur"},{"id":43,"name":"Radio's"},{"id":36,"name":"Stereo-sets"},{"id":45,"name":"Tuners"},{"id":1118,"name":"Tv-decoders en Schotelantennes"},{"id":1120,"name":"Tv's | Plasma, Lcd en Led"},{"id":1121,"name":"Tv's | Overige Tv's"},{"id":1453,"name":"Tv's | Accessoires"},{"id":46,"name":"Versterkers en Receivers"},{"id":1129,"name":"Videobewakingsapparatuur"},{"id":1130,"name":"Videocamera's | Analoog"},{"id":1131,"name":"Videocamera's | Digitaal"},{"id":1133,"name":"Videospelers en Videorecorders"},{"id":47,"name":"Walkmans, Discmans en Minidiscspelers"},{"id":1725,"name":"Weerstations en Barometers"},{"id":41,"name":"Overige Audio, Tv en Foto"}]}}';

$result = preg_replace('/[\{\[]\s*(\d+)\s*:/', '"\\0"', $string);
```

This will convert integer keys into strings leaving integer values as integer.

Comment: According to `jsonlint`, it expects the zero `0` to be a string. I cannot parse this string using PHP, it will return `NULL`.

Comment: @Devator Ok, then what you're after is to convert your string into the proper JSON.  See my updates.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick:

```
$json = preg_replace('/(\d+):/', '"$1":', $almost_json);
```

Comment: It's not working correctly. It also changes integers which reside inside a string, for example: `{"id":2127,"name":"Modelauto's | "1":5 tot "1":12"}`. As you see the `1` is now `"1"`.